# Получение сообщений от бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делаю бота для репортов. Задача в том, чтобы сообщения отправлялись от имени бота юзеру по реплаю. Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['send'])
     def process_start(message):
if int(message.chat.id) == owner:
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Reply message')
        bot.forward_message(owner, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_mind)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Crash! Error:\n<code>@bot.message_handler("
                         "commands=['send_message'])</code>",
                         parse_mode='HTML')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Permission denied!')
def process_mind(message):
if int(message.chat.id) == owner:
    try:
        text = 'Message sent! ' + str(message.reply_to_message.forward_from.first_name)
        bot.send_message(message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id, message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(owner, text)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Crash! Error:\n\n <code>def process_mind(message)</code>',
                         parse_mode='HTML')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Permission denied!')
```

После отправки сообщения юзеру, ему от бота приходит содержимое getMe, а не сообщение с ответом. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: какую проблему?

Comment: Проблему с отправкой сообщений. Чтобы вместо таких данных "{'document': None, 'new_chat_member': None, 'group_chat_created': None, 'chat': {'first_name': None, 'photo': None, 'last_name': None, 'sticker_set_name': None, 'id': 123, 'pinned_message': None, 'type': 'group', 'can_set_sticker_set': None, 'invite_link': None, 'title': 'test', 'username': None, 'description': None, 'all_members_are_administrators':"", отправлялось только сообщение.

Comment: вы, шайтан, какую-то ахинею несёте. покажите код для начала, покажите результат кода, покажите свои ожидания. тогда на вопрос можно будет ответить, а сейчас - ничего не понятно

Comment: Пофиксил, добавил кусок кода